# How to match Subject verb agreement in this type of sentence?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> The chips, derived from designs by ARM, which is based in Britain, will be similar to those that already power its smartphones and tablets.

In this sentence, which of the following subject takes the  verb ? I need to understand the all subject-verb- agreement in this sentence

Comment: I don't follow you. "Which" is not a verb but a relative pronoun.

Comment: I mean, which of the following subject takes verb? can you match all sub -verb- agreement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original phrasing of this question was a bit better, although not perfect.   Agreement is barely at issue.   There is nothing here worth marking as ***the*** verb.   If I understand you correctly, the question at hand is simply this:

#### In this sentence, which subject takes which verb?

Let's start with finding verbs that want subjects.   Under a traditional analysis, that's the same as finding which verbs are finite:

> The chips, derived from designs by ARM, which **is** based in Britain, **will** be similar to those that already **power** its smartphones and tablets.

There are other verbs in the sentence.   We can find "derived" and "based" and "be".   None of those take subjects in this sentence.   We'll pass by them and explain why this is so on our way toward finding each subject that does exist.

The first finite verb is "is".   It creates the predicate "is based in Britain".   Here, "based" is traditionally analyzed as part of the predicating phrase "is based".   We don't need to find a separate subject for "based", since finding a subject for the entire phrase is enough.   We call this construction a *passive present-tense* verb.   The subject of this predicate is "which" -- a relative pronoun that attaches this entire clause to its antecedent, the acronym "ARM".   From this, we know that *ARM is based in Britain*.   On its own, "which" doesn't have a grammatical number.   We treat it as either singular or plural depending on its antecedent.   Here, "is" agrees with the singular meaning of "ARM", since that's the meaning which this "which" carries.

The second finite verb is "will".   It creates the predicate "will be similar to those that already power its smartphones and tablets".   Here, the predicating phrase is "will be".   Grammatically, that's a present-tense verb.   Semantically, it's *future indefinite* (sometimes badly labeled as *simple future*).   The verb form "will" agrees with any subject -- either singular or plural; either first-, second- or third-person.   Its simple subject is "chips".   Its complete subject is "the chips, derived from designs by ARM, which is based in Britain".

You might notice that this complete subject contains the verb "derived".   This "derived" is not part of a predicating verb phrase.  It's a participle, which is a non-finite form.   Under a traditional analysis, we treat "derived from designs by ARM..." as a *participial phrase* and as a nonrestrictive modifier of "the chips".   It still licenses a semantic *patient* -- some things which are derived -- but that patient is supplied by its modificand, not by some subject which we would have to either invent or overload.

From the future indefinite clause, we can guess that the new chips of its subject ***will be** derived* from designs by ARM, but that they do not exist yet.

The third and last finite verb is "power".   It creates the predicate "already power its smartphones and tablets".   The predicating verb phrase has only one word, so, instead of calling it a verb phrase, we call it *simple*.   This is a *simple present-tense verb*.   Its subject is the relative pronoun "that" -- a relative pronoun that attaches its clause to its antecedent, the demonstrative substantive adjective "those".   The more traditional label for this substantive adjective is simply *pronoun*.   From this, we know that *some chips already power its smartphones and tablets.*

At this point, we've addressed every verb.   We've identified the finite verbs -- the ones that want to be bound to a subject.   We've identified each subject, and each subject/predicate pairing.   We've looked at the one example where subject/verb agreement is relevant.   We've even suggested reasons to leave the non-finite verbs out of our accounting.

All of that leads us to a short list of pairs, simple subjects with simple predicates:

- which  /  is based
- chips  /  will be
- those  /  power

#### This is how to match subjects with verbs in this type of sentence.